# Can't figure out the SQL code

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE empinf(
companyid varchar2(5) PRIMARY KEY,
companyname varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
emailid varchar2(20) REFERENCES usrinf(emailid),
Mobile number CONSTRAINT moc CHECK(LENGTH(Mobile)=10),
city varchar2(20),
industrytype varchar2(20),
functionalarea varchar2(20),
membershipplan varchar2(20) CONSTRAINT cmp CHECK(membershipplan in ('TRIAL','PREMIUM MONTHLY','PREMIUM YEARLY')),
dateofsignup date DEFAULT SYSDATE CONSTRAINT chd CHECK( dateofsignup>=SYSDATE ),
dateofrenewal date generated always as 
    (CASE
        WHEN membershipplan='TRIAL' THEN SYSDATE+14 
        WHEN membershipplan='PREMIUM MONTHLY' THEN SYSDATE+30
        WHEN membershipplan='PREMIUM YEARLY' THEN SYSDATE+365
        ELSE SYSDATE
    END
    ) virtual,
renewalstatus varchar2(20) CONSTRAINT chrs CHECK(renewalstatus in('ACTIVE','EXPIRED')),
CONSTRAINT mun UNIQUE(Mobile)
)
```

This code is to be generated in Oracle Express 11G, I am unable to figure out what's wrong with code, it shows 'missing paranthesis error'.

Comment: Is 'missing parethesis error' the whole error message?

Comment: It's seems to me problem could be in CASE for DATEOFRENEWAL (SQL Error: ORA-54002: only pure functions can be specified in a virtual column expression)

Comment: I would suggest the following: Write a statement that creates the basic structure of the table. Then start adding Primary / Foreign key constraints, then add unique/ normal indexes and finally add the Check constraints. That way you will understand the different parts of the statement clearly and in case of a problem, you would point it out more easily. The example here must be re-written almost completely in order to work, so start from the basics.

Comment: @afonte yes.'ORA-00907 Missing Right Paranthesis' is the whole error message.

Comment: @etsa so how do i re-write that?

Comment: @g00dy The requirement is to generate values of dateofrenewal field based on the value in membershipplan field. So how do u suggest, I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is strange you are getting a "missing paranthesis" error. Maybe the tool you are using to execute the statement swallows the last paranthesis?

I am getting "ORA-02436: date or system variable wrongly specified in CHECK constraint"

```
CONSTRAINT chd CHECK( dateofsignup>=SYSDATE )
```

You cannot use `SYSDATE` in a check constraint, as `SYSDATE` is subject to change. A check constraint must be stable and must not depend on the current time, a current session setting or the like. You'd need a trigger to do what you want to do.

After removing that check constraint I get "ORA-54002: only pure functions can be specified in a virtual column expression", which is about for the same reason.

```
dateofrenewal date generated always as 
    (CASE
        WHEN membershipplan='TRIAL' THEN SYSDATE+14 
...
```

A virtual column must be stable and can only depend on other columns, not  on the current time, a current session setting or the like. You probably want `dateofrenewal` to be calculated based on `dateofsignup` instead.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, in a virtual column you need to define a deterministic function (a one which return same value, irrespective of when you call it.

You could try to use dateofsignup instead of SYSDATE inside case .

```
dateofrenewal date generated always as 
    (CASE
        WHEN membershipplan='TRIAL' THEN dateofsignup+14 
        WHEN membershipplan='PREMIUM MONTHLY' THEN dateofsignup+30
        WHEN membershipplan='PREMIUM YEARLY' THEN dateofsignup+365
        ELSE dateofsignup
    END
    ) virtual
```

Or you can remove it from table and use a view.

I forgot the other error (I was concentrating on the first one, so I apologize for the miss).  As Thorsten say in other answer, you have a problem to set a check constraint for datesignup in that way.
Other that solution Torstein suggested, another solution could be to add another column (eg. `DATE_INSERT DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE`)

and write the constraint changing datesignup definition as

`dateofsignup date DEFAULT SYSDATE`

and  add

`ALTER TABLE empinf ADD CONSTRAINT chd CHECK( dateofsignup>=DATE_INSERT)`

Your missing parenthesis error can be caused by your tries, while you commented some parts of the code.

Tip: I agree with g00dy comment above: create table basic structure with one command, then add constraint with separate commands.